# Linking Font Awesome icon to Rails attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, font-awesome

I'm trying to have a Font Awesome icon be hyperlinked with the string of a Rails attribute.

I have tried this,

```
  <%= link_to do %>
    <i class="fa fa-link"><% school.website %></i>
  <% end %>
```

this,

```
<i class="fa fa-link" href="<% school.website %>"></i>
```

and this:

```
<i class="fa fa-link" href="<%= school.website %>"></i>
```

among other variations, and can't seem to get the syntax right.

Would really appreciate some help with the syntax here, can't seem to find a specific answer to how linking with attributes works, only actual static text hrefs.

PS: I'm new to Rails / using Rails 4.2.

Comment: It would really help if you showed us what the error was for each of the above (ie the undesired output) - and give us a sample of what your desired output would be?

Comment: Also: `<% school.website %>`  will never work - you must use `<%=` in order for output to actually appear on the page

Comment: Finally: can you give as a made-up example of what `school.website` would look like? does it have `http://` in it?

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
<%= link_to ('<i class="fa fa-link"></i>').html_safe, desired_path  %>
```

Comment: This prepends my current URL to the desired URL and takes me to: 
[link](http://localhost:3000/www.codecore.ca) 
because I need to use 

`<%= link_to ('<i class="fa fa-link"></i>').html_safe, school.website  %>`

for your example.

Comment: desired_path needs to be the rails path where you want it to go. Where do you want it to go in your application? Run `rake routes` and pass the route you want to `link_to` with an appended `_path`

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. What you provided is correct syntax. However, this will only work when the the `school.website` has a value of `https://...`. Otherwise it thinks it's a path and tack it on as a slug. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Considering school.website is a URL and you have included icons in CSS, the following will do:

```
<%= link_to(school.website) do %>
    <i class="fa fa-link"></i>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Passing it as a block works too.

```
 <%= link_to school.website do  %>
   <%= '<i class="fa fa-link"></i>'.html_safe %>
 <% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming school.website is a URL that you would like to link to and display the link as well alongside the link icon from font awesome:

```
<%= link_to("<i class='fa fa-link'></i> #{school.website}".html_safe,school.website) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am going to suggest something a little different.

I am personlly using glyphicons/fa a lot on my website, so I decided to create a little helper in application_helper.rb

**application_helper.rb**

```
def fa(glyph, text = nil)
    html = "<i class=\"fa fa-#{glyph}\"></i>"
    html << " #{text.to_s.html_safe}" if text
    html.html_safe
end
```

And actually the correct syntax to use in views becomes either :

```
<%= link_to(school.website, class: "xxx") do %>
  <%= fa('link') %>
<% end %>
```

OR (more compact)

```
<%= link_to(school.website, class: "xxx"){ fa('link') } %>
```

Comment: I remember one of `button_to/link_to` does not support html as "text" argument, so it is a good habit to use blocks to provide the html text content

Answer (score 0):

You can use a block as well if your link target is hard to fit into the name parameter. ERB example:

try this:

```
<%= link_to(school.website) do %>
    <%= fa_icon "fas link" %>
<% end %>
```